# How to install Tensorboard on WIndows

Tags: tensorboard

I installed Python 3.7.4 on my Window 7 (64bit) computer (Core i5, 8 GB RAM) for all users (i.e. into C:\Program Files\Python37).
The I installed TensorFlow. Strangly, it went into my user folders: `C:\Users\bernhard.hiller\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\tensorboard.exe`and additional folders at `C:\Users\bernhard.hiller\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow`.
There is also a Tensorboard folder parallel to that: `C:\Users\bernhard.hiller\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard`
But I cannot run tensorboard (a command not found error is shown on the windows command line - I did not see a `tensorboard.exe` anywhere).

Next, I followed the isntallation steps for Bazel found at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-windows.html MSYS2 was installed - as recommended - into C:\msys64 (on Windows 7, as if it was Widnwos 95). Then I downloaded the latest bazel executable, renamed it to bazel.exe and placed it into the folder of Python.

When calling `bazel build tensorboard:tensorboard`, I receive a FATAL error:

`C:\Windows\system32>bazel build tensorboard:tensorboard
FATAL: ExecuteProgram(C:\Users\bernhard.hiller/_bazel_bernhard.hiller/install/a4
556c0a24a7f5c72797f234cbf35797/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/bin/java.ex
e) failed: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(184): CreateProcessW("C:\Us
ers\bernhard.hiller\_bazel_bernhard.hiller\install\a4556c0a24a7f5c72797f234cbf35
797\_embedded_binaries\embedded_tools\jdk\bin\java.exe"  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMem
oryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=c:\(...)): Nicht gen³gend Systemressourcen, um den ang
eforderten Dienst auszuf³hren.`

I.e. insufficient system ressources

What can I do now? Are there other ways to get tensorboard running?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I created a batch file `Tensorboard.bat` and placed it into the Python folder (C:\Program Files\Python37).

Its contents are:

```
C:
cd \
python c:\Users\bernhard.hiller\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py --logdir="%1"
```

After calling `tensorboard C:/Some/Path/to/my_graph` (note: do not use backslashes `\`, only forward slashes `/`),
`http://localhost:6006` can be opened in Chrome. It fails with Firefox and Internet Explorer.

WTF. But it works (TM).